# Terence Tao, Analysis I book exercise 9.8.5, an example of function discontinuous at every rational, but continuous at every irrational point

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity

[Exercise description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3Xwe.png)

I've got through every exercise in Tao Analysis book, but this one cracked me.

I can't quite understand why this function isn't constant, even though I somehow loosely proved that the property a) holds.
The function is defined as series $f(x)=\sum_\limits{r\in\mathcal{Q}, r < x}{g(r=q(n))}$ where $g(q(n))=\frac{1}{2^n}$. Does it mean that function evaluates by definition as some infinity series like $\sum_\limits{r\in\mathcal{Q}}{\frac{1}{2^n}}$? If so, then the series should evaluate to 2 at every point, since between each two points on a real line there is a set of rational points of countable cardinality. I'm sure this is the place where my logic fails, but still I can't quite grasp why the function isn't constant (even though that is counterintuitive), or why it is discontinious at every rational point.

I tried to apply logic from other similar functions like Thomae's function, which is pretty straightforward to understand why this function has similar properties. But unfortunatelly I failed

So, please any help on how to work with such strange functions, and in particulary with this one

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your confusion is rooted in the notation. As in the exercise description, let $q: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Q}$ be the bijection and $q^{-1}: \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{N}$ be its inverse. Then the function is simply

$f:  \mathbb{R} \to [0,2],   x \mapsto \sum_{r<x, r \in \mathbb{Q}} 2^{-q^{-1}(r)}  $

So as you can see the sum involved sums over countably many rational numbers (as there are infinitely many rational numbers below any real $x \in \mathbb{R}$), but not over all rational numbers, i.e.

$\{ r \in \mathbb{Q} | r < x  \} \subsetneq \{ r \in \mathbb{Q} \} $

Hence $f$ is not constant, e.g. it could be $f(x_0) = 1 + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{64} + \dots \neq 2 $. Note also, that $\forall x : f(x) < 2 $, since for every real number, there is a rational number that is larger than that.

With this in mind the (b) should be fairly straightforward to solve, given the hint that is already there in the description.